# Deleting images from a file with c++

Tags: c++

I want to delete images from a file, the images are named: "1.jpg, 2.jpg ....", i have tried the code above but it gives me this error: no matching function for call to 'remove(std::__cxx11::string&)'

```
 int i;
 for (i=0;i<frame;i++)//frame contain the number of images i want to delete
 {
      std::stringstream ss;
     ss << i;
     std::string str = ss.str();
     const char *cstr = str.c_str();
     str=str+".jpg";
     remove(str);
 }
```

If someone can help thank you in advence.

Comment: Which documenting reference states that `remove` takes a `std::string`?

Comment: I used to use remove("image.jpg") and it worked

Comment: "image.jpg" is not a `std::string`. Don't make assumptions, but instead _study_ and _read_ in order to obtain _facts_.

Comment: I'm a beginner with c++ programming, thank you for the information and the advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it.  `remove` requires a `const char*`, not a `std::string`.  That means you need

```
remove(str.c_str());
```

---

We can also get rid of the `stringstream` and use `std::to_string` instead in something like

```
for (i=0; i<frame; i++)
{
    const std::string str = to_string(i) + ".jpg";
    remove(str.c_str());
}
```